# IBM-MQ kubernetes helm chart MaxChannels value

Tags: ibm-mq

I want to change    MaxChannels value, it is inside the qm.ini file. Is there any option with helm variable or do i need to rebuild image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the IBM sample Helm Chart available [here](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-helm), you can specify a qm.ini within a Kubernetes configMap and then reference this as part of the Helm deployment. Each of the samples already reference a qm.ini which you can use as an example. The qm.ini is created within a ConfigMap [here](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-helm/blob/67e4bf5b1f70c5cf972af56ec28fe4fa926b8fdd/samples/AWSEKS/deploy/mtlsqm.yaml_template#L14), and referenced [here](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-helm/blob/67e4bf5b1f70c5cf972af56ec28fe4fa926b8fdd/samples/AWSEKS/deploy/secureapp_nativeha.yaml#L24).